# find non blank cell value , which maches the criteria vloockup or mathc

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

```
Col1     Col2
Name     unique id
A         
B         2000
B         2000
A         3000
C         1010
```

Now search A's unique id, using vlookup or match, it should return 3000.

Comment: What have you researched and attempted yourself. Currently there is also no question in here.

Comment: Typically a search will result in the first match, which is an empty cell in your example. Do you need the match to exclude blank results?

Comment: yes,
i need from next time if i give input as A it should be out filled with 3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this:

`INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1,(A:A="A")*(B:B<>""),0))`

This is an array function, to be entered with `ctrl + shift + enter`

The formula checks if both conditions `A:A="A"` and (`*`) `B:B<>""` are true and finds the row number of the first match and returns the value of that row in column B.

Comment: For better understanding: `1` in the MATCH section of the formula can be read as True (can also be typed as True in the formula).